# Can one dichlorotriazine molecule form two bonds with cellulose?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, biochemistry

In all the reactions I saw online, dichlorotriazine is shown to form only one bond with cellulose ([example 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_dye#Usage), [example 2](http://www.pburch.net/dyeing/dyeblog/C1845207367/E346098115/); [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021979796946524)).

But cellulose has [many potential sites for bonding](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cellulose_strand.svg). Can dichlorotriazine actually give up both Cl atoms for forming two bonds with cellulose?

Comment: Yes, see p. 374 [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=jXd-LhCkf9sC&pg=PA374&lpg=PA374&dq=can+dichlorotriazine+react+at+both+chlorines&source=bl&ots=QHMNfYq_xL&sig=7Dn56sMHM4jgKvtTOUyithBsil4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=A4BBVfO7I8mNyASJ74GQCw&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=can%20dichlorotriazine%20react%20at%20both%20chlorines&f=false)

Comment: @ron, that's exactly what I was looking for!